# .NET Extension Events

Tags: .net, events, extension-methods

I want to add events to some built in .NET classes.  For example I want to add the following events to a generic `List(T)`:

- ItemAdded
- ItemRemoved
- ListChanged
- etc

I can think of a few ways to accomplish this, but I'm not sure which approach is best.

1. I could use "*extension events*", that is, if there is such a thing or a way to use extension methods to simulate event-like functionality.
2. I could inherit from `List(T)` and *override* the necessary methods and properties.
3. I could inherit from `List(T)` and *shadow* the necessary methods and properties.
4. I could create a new class that implements `IList(T)` and then wrap the remaining functionality of `List(T)` that `IList(T)` is missing.

Obviously option 4 is the most work, which is not a big deal if I only wanted to extend one class.  However, I also want to avoid nasty side effects.

What are the advantages, disadvantages, and caveats for each approach?

Note:  I'm not really concerned here with IList(T) specifically.  I find myself wanting  to add "extenstion events" to other classes as well.

Comment: That may not be what you are looking for but you could use ObservableCollection<T>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There's no such thing as "extension events" and you can't use extension methods to simulate this: extension events can't add state to existing classes, which is what you'd require.
2. I think you mean *override* rather than *overload*. This will work, this it's slightly clumsy - and means you couldn't use the normal `ToList` from LINQ etc, because then you'd just get a `List<T>`.
3. Shadowing is nastier than overriding. It means that the events may or may not be raised based on how the caller is calling the method. Ick.
4. This would be preferable, and you could add an extension method to `List<T>` to wrap it. One disadvantage is that if anyone else "knows about" the *unwrapped* collection, you won't spot changes made that way.

Have you looked at [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)? Note that this will *copy* from a list if you provide it in the constructor, rather than *wrapping* the list.

Comment: 4. Is the disadvantage in implementing IList(T) or in using an extension method to List(T) to wrap it?  Secondly, I'm not sure how to use an extension method to List(T) to wrap it...

Answer (score 2):

"extension events" don't exist, nor do extension properties or anything other than extension methods. Personally I'd like to see extension properties (given that they're just wrappers for functions), but I'm not sure how you could implement extension events in the static fashion that extensions require.

There is nothing stopping you from adding those events to the class itself. However, you might have more success looking at `BindingList<T>`, since it's more in line with the monitoring activity you appear to want to do.